# Json decode always return nil

Tags: json, swift

I am created a swiftui app but for test purpose, I have a create a mocked repo to return the data from a json instead of placing an api call. The result of the `JSONDecode` is always nil...

the Json is as below and stored at the root project like the google.plist, ContentView and so on.

```
[
    {
        "ts": 1000000,
        "id": 1,
        "userName": "honeybee",
        "userLocation": "Honey bee",
        "userImageUrl": "user_1",
        "title": "Here",
        "postType": "post",
        "postImageUrl": "food_1",
    },
    {
        "ts": 1000000,
        "id": 2,
        "userName": "honeybee",
        "userLocation": "Honey bee",
        "userImageUrl": "user_2",
        "title": "Here",
        "postType": "store",
        "postImageUrl": "food_2"
    },
```

I created a model `FeedItemEntity` as below:

```
enum PostType: String, Codable {
    case Post =  "post"
    case Store = "store"
    case Restaurant = "restaurant"
    case Review = "review"
    case Recipe = "recipe"
}

struct FeedItemEntity: Codable {
    var ts: Int
    var userName: String
    var userLocation: String
    var userImageUrl: String
    var title: String
    var postImageUrl: String
    var postType: PostType
    var rating: Int
}

extension FeedItemEntity: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID {
        let id = UUID()
        return id
    }
}
```

and then my code is doing this:

```
class MockedFeedService: FeedServiceProtocol {
    
    static let shared = MockedFeedService()

    
    func getFeed() -> Future<[ios_foodloose_app.FeedItemEntity], Error> {
        return Future<[FeedItemEntity], Error> { promise in
            
            guard let url = Bundle(for: MockedFeedService.self).url(forResource: "basic-test-feed-response",withExtension: "json"),
                  let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
                return promise(.failure(NSError(domain: "", code: 401, userInfo: [ NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Error"])))
            }
            
            let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode( [FeedItemEntity].self, from: data)
            promise(.success(response!))
        }
    }
    
}
```

in my case `response` is always `nil`

Any idea why ?

Thanks

Comment: Replace `try?` with `try` in a `do catch` block and print the `error`. And the `Future` is pointless. Decoding JSON is synchronous.

Comment: Another one that uses `try?`... I haven't tried your code but you have and `id` in your json but your custom type implements its own `id` logic. This looks a bit suspicious.

Comment: pay attention to the details, there is no `rating` in your json, in addition to all the other comments. Try again with the comments advice.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON file doesn't contain a `rating` field.

You can update your `basic-test-feed-response.json` by either adding a `rating` field to all items of the array or make the optional `rating` field in the `FeedItemEntity` model like this:

```
struct FeedItemEntity: Codable {
    var ts: Int
    var userName: String
    var userLocation: String
    var userImageUrl: String
    var title: String
    var postImageUrl: String
    var postType: PostType
    var rating: Int?
}
```

You can use `do-catch` mechanism to obtain a description of what went wrong:

```
do {
    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode([FeedItemEntity].self, from: data)
    promise(.success(response))
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

In Xcode console, you will see:

> keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "rating", intValue: nil),
> Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index
> 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key
> CodingKeys(stringValue: "rating", intValue: nil) ("rating").",
> underlyingError: nil))

Answer (score 0):

This will work, I made some adjustment in JSON and Decoder. Please modify it as per your need.

```
import Foundation

let json = """
[
    {
        "ts": 1000000,
        "id": 1,
        "userName": "honeybee",
        "userLocation": "Honey bee",
        "userImageUrl": "user_1",
        "title": "Here",
        "postType": "post",
        "postImageUrl": "food_1"
    },
    {
        "ts": 1000000,
        "id": 2,
        "userName": "honeybee",
        "userLocation": "Honey bee",
        "userImageUrl": "user_2",
        "title": "Here",
        "postType": "store",
        "postImageUrl": "food_2"
    }
]
""".data(using: .utf8)!
print (json)

enum PostType: String, Codable {
    case Post =  "post"
    case Store = "store"
    case Restaurant = "restaurant"
    case Review = "review"
    case Recipe = "recipe"
}

struct FeedItemEntity: Codable {
    var ts: Int
    var userName: String
    var userLocation: String
    var userImageUrl: String
    var title: String
    var postImageUrl: String
    var postType: PostType
}

extension FeedItemEntity: Identifiable {
    var id: String {
        let id = UUID().uuidString
        return id
    }
}

// create a JSON decoder
let decoder = JSONDecoder()

// decode the JSON into your model object and print the result
do {
    let feed = try decoder.decode([FeedItemEntity].self, from: json)
    print(feed)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```